# Didnt return a response - Duplicate django users

Tags: python, json, django, django-forms, django-views

I have a django project. I have integrated djangos signup and login system into my application. I have a method for creating a user and logging them into the current session. I notices that when I try to create a record for a users with an existing username in the database, instead of giving a unique constraint fail or redirecting to another page, it just throws the following error:

```
ValueError at /signup/
The view users.views.user_signup didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/signup/
Django Version: 1.11.5
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
The view users.views.user_signup didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
Exception Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response, line 198
Python Executable:  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.6.2
Python Path:    
['/Users/omarjandali/Desktop/split/split',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python36.zip',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
```

Now I am using printing and logging to see where this issue is occuring and there is nothing printing. I feel like the form is not going to the method it was called from... I have no idea what is going on with this. Can anyone help...

process =
if form not submitted -> display from
fill out for -> grab info from form -> grab useranem and see if there is already a account with this username or email -> if no account -> create and save user object -> login the user to session ===> if account -> redirect to the test page... Here is my code:

```
def user_signup(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SignupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            username = cd['username']
            password = cd['password']
            verify = cd['verify']
            email = cd['email']
            valid_user = User.objects.filter(username = username).first()
            if valid_user == None:
                if password == verify:
                    secure_password = make_password(password)
                    user = User.objects.create(
                        username = username,
                        password = secure_password,
                        email = email,
                    )
                    login(request, user)
                    return redirect('test')
                else:
                    form = SignupForm()
                    parameters = {
                        'form':form,
                    }
                    return render(request, 'users/signup.html', parameters)
            else:
                return redirect('test')
    else:
        form = SignupForm()
        parameters = {
            'form':form
        }
        return render(request, 'users/signup.html', parameters)
```

the form shows up and I can fill it out but the second i submit the form, everything goes wrong.... The form exists in my forms.py file. I have no idea why it is telling me there is no http response when there is.

---

I have a retruned validation error within the form and I want to grab the message from the error response.

the response is a json repsonse below:

```
{"username": 
  [
    {
     "message": "A user with that username already exists.",
     "code": "unique"
     }
   ]
}
```

I want to grab just the message. I have the following code to grab the message... it is not working...

```
error_json['username'][0]['message']
```

the error message:

```
string indices must be integers
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't processed case when `form.is_valid()` returns `False`. In such case your view returns `None`.

Comment: oh. ok I will try implimenting something real quick. thank you

Comment: It worked, but now how do i figure out why my form is not valid... and why it is not valid....

Comment: After form validation you have all errors stored in `form.errors`, you can try to simply print it. More from docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#rendering-form-error-messages

Comment: I am going to update my post with another question under the original post about print the error message from json.

Comment: I think you should ask a new question instead of editing your exisiting question...